# Safari won't log in with Devise and Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, safari

I have a Rails 4.0.11.1 app that uses Devise for user auth. It runs fine in development and production on all major browsers except  Safari 8. It works fine on mobile Safari and it works in really old versions of Safari.  I am getting a 422 Unprocessable Entity error. Here is part of the error:

```
Started POST "/auth/signin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-21 11:19:17 -0700
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token"=>"HGlp4uhzhmgtoVZoWvwpk5EtL5UqiqiwjIRfJlUyjEU=", 
"user"=>{"email"=>"bwood@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", 
"remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms
```

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941714/rails-3-2-app-on-heroku-with-devise-cant-log-in-with-mobile-safari) post and tried their solution: Adding the following code to session_store.rb

```
domain: :all
```

This did not do the trick for me. Has anyone solved an issue similar to this with Safari 8?

Solved: Bit of a bonehead move. My Safari setting were set to block all cookies. I changed that and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Great blog post about the issue you are having check it out http://blog.softr.li/post/43146401263/finally-correctly-dealing-with-rails-csrf

Comment: This difference, I think, between the issue you reference and my issue is that I am not able to signin the first time. Even when trying to create a new user I get there error immediately after I submit the form.

Comment: If you have a solution, write about it in the answer box provided. This is preferable to editing the word "solved" into the question.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your web browser is accepting cookies. If it is not, then you will be unable to complete authentication (not just here, but on most web sites).